# How to resize rectangle in d3 js

Tags: d3.js

Right now I am able to resize a circle. I have created a rectangle using `g.append('svg:rect')` but I am not sure how to resize a rectangle in d3

This is what I have tried:

```
var boxWidth = 1300;
var boxHeight = 600;

var box = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'box')
        .attr('width', boxWidth)
        .attr('height', boxHeight);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {
            g.selectAll('*')
                    .attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                    .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
        });

var resize = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {
            g.selectAll('.resizingContainer')
                    .attr('r', function (c) {
                        return Math.pow(Math.pow(this.attributes.cx.value - d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.attributes.cy.value - d3.event.y, 2), 0.5) + 6;
                    });
            g.selectAll('.draggableCircle')
                    .attr('r', function (c) {
                        return Math.pow(Math.pow(this.attributes.cx.value - d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.attributes.cy.value - d3.event.y, 2), 0.5);
                    });
        });

var g = box.selectAll('.draggableGroup')
        .data([{
                x: 65,
                y: 55,
                r: 25
            }])
        .enter()
        .append('g');

g.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'resizingContainer')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.r + 6;
        })
        .style('fill', '#999')
        .call(resize);

g.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.r;
        })
        .call(drag)
        .style('fill', 'black');

g.append('svg:rect')
        .attr("width", 70)
        .attr("height", 70)
        .attr("x", 30)
        .attr("y", 130)
        .attr("rx", 6)
        .attr("ry", 6)
        .style("fill", d3.scale.category20c());
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src='d3.js' charset='utf-8'></script>

        <style>
            .box {
                border: 1px black;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            .resizingContainer {
                cursor: nesw-resize;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src='drag.js'></script>
        <div id="checks">
        X-axis:<input type="checkbox" id="xChecked" checked/>
        Y-axis:<input type="checkbox" id="yChecked" checked/>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the live demo: https://jsbin.com/dejewumali/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You should probably make a JSFiddle for it. It will help you get responses.

Comment: updated the question with link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added rectangle resize for your code. Note that you need to use the bottom right corner for resizing (that was the easiest corner to add the resizing to :-))

```
var boxWidth = 1300;
var boxHeight = 600;

var box =
    d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'box')
        .attr('width', boxWidth)
        .attr('height', boxHeight);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {
            g.selectAll('*')
                .attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                .attr('cy', d3.event.y);
        });

var resize = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {
            g.selectAll('.resizingContainer')
                    .attr('r', function (c) {
                        return Math.pow(Math.pow(this.attributes.cx.value - d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.attributes.cy.value - d3.event.y, 2), 0.5) + 6;
                    });
            g.selectAll('.circle')
                    .attr('r', function (c) {
                        return Math.pow(Math.pow(this.attributes.cx.value - d3.event.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.attributes.cy.value - d3.event.y, 2), 0.5);
                    });
        });


var g = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle')
        .data([{
            x: 65,
            y: 55,
            r: 25
        }])
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'draggableCircle');

g.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'resizingContainer')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.r + 6;
        })
        .style('fill', '#999')
        .call(resize);

g.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr('r', function (d) {
            return d.r;
        })
        .call(drag)
        .style('fill', 'black');


var distance = function (p1, p2) {
    return Math.pow(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2), 0.5);
}

var resize2 = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('drag', function () {
            var c = g2.selectAll('.resizingSquare');
            var s = g2.selectAll('.square');

            var e = d3.event;
            var x = Number(this.attributes.x.value);
            var y = Number(this.attributes.y.value);
            var w = Number(this.attributes.width.value);
            var h = Number(this.attributes.height.value);
            var c1 = { x: x, y: y };
            var c2 = { x: x + w, y: y };
            var c3 = { x: x + w, y: y + h };
            var c4 = { x: x, y: y + h };

            // figure out which corner this is closest to
            var d = []
            var m1 = distance(e, c1)
            var m2 = distance(e, c2)
            var m3 = distance(e, c3)
            var m4 = distance(e, c4)
            switch (Math.min(m1, m2, m3, m4)) {
                case m3:
                    c
                        .attr('width', function () { return w + (e.x - c3.x) + 12 })
                        .attr('height', function () { return h + (e.y - c3.y) + 12 })
                    s
                        .attr('width', function () { return w + (e.x - c3.x) })
                        .attr('height', function () { return h + (e.y - c3.y) })
                    break;
            }
        });

var g2 = box.selectAll('.draggableSquare')
    .data([{
        x: 65,
        y: 155,
        width: 70,
        height: 70
    }])
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'draggableSquare');

g2
    .append('svg:rect')
        .attr('class', 'resizingSquare')
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return d.width + 12;
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.height + 12;
        })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x - 6;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y - 6;
        })
        .attr("rx", 6)
        .attr("ry", 6)
        .style("fill", '#999')
        .call(resize2);

g2
    .append('svg:rect')
        .attr('class', 'square')
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return d.width;
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return d.height;
        })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return d.y;
        })
        .attr("rx", 6)
        .attr("ry", 6)
        .style("fill", d3.scale.category20c());
```

JS Bin - https://jsbin.com/zenomoziso/1/edit

---

That said, if you are looking to use this beyond a proof of concept it's going to be very difficult. There are several problems with the above that will manifest once you have more elements

1. The container (g or g2) being used is a global variable.
2. The code is clunky (I just tacked on most of it based on the watches - there could be far more efficient ways of doing the same thing - e.g. you could not the start position onDragStart and use that to calculate the change in dimensions)
3. The code could be cleaner (think objects, better naming conventions, etc.). You might just want do `d3.data... squares({ resize: true, move: true })` in your main block instead of all the individual steps.
4. You'll be better off searching for some existing diagramming library (why do all the math, when it's already done and tested :-)) - I found a blog with the canvas variant here - http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful

Comment: Thank you so much for solution but my manager wants me to create a work flow like this  http://rigrr.rapilabs.com/    in svg. I am hitting my head to wall thinking which library to go for to achieve workflows. P.S I am still new to even basic js :(

Comment: http://www.jointjs.com/ looks nice. http://modeling-languages.com/javascript-drawing-libraries-diagrams/ has a list. But I haven't used any of them for diagramming.

Comment: Joint js doesn't look good in style...and styling for links isn't customisable as far I can see....I checked it today it self

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle size is based on the `width` and `height` attributes. Thus to resize the rectangle you'll want to use something of this ilk:

```
 d3.selectAll('rect')
        .attr('width', function(c){
          return d3.event.x - this.attributes.x.value;
      }).attr('height', function(c){
          return d3.event.y - this.attributes.y.value;
      });
```

Inserted into your `resize` behaviour. If you do this and click to drag the circle and move to the origin of the rectangle, it'll then expand linearly with your cursor. It will likely work with little modification if the drag event was attached to the rectangle. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mccannf/1629464) is a simple application that showcases dragging and re-sizing of a rectangle.

For more reliability you'd want to select by a class identifier rather than a global rectangle select, but this is the basic idea.